# Instantiation of class inside method vs autowire in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring

service class and repository class are `autowired` in spring mvc. but the entity and dto classes are instantiated within method. Is there any specific reason.

```
@Autowired
TestService testService;
```

but for method instantiation

```
public TestDto getData(){
    TestDto testDto = new TestDto();
    /*Some task*/
    return testDto;
}
```

why the dto classes are not autowired while writing code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "why the dto class can't be autowired" who said that?? (side note, code should be `return testDto;`)

Comment: yeah thanks for the side note. but in most cases, the dtos are instantiated inside method, why it is not autowired.

Comment: you should ask the author, not us

Comment: This is not specific to author. but most of the examples have such structure.

Answer (score 3):

If I were writing the code you've presented I would have also created a DTO with "new" inside the method just like an author. I'll explain why and hopefully it will provide some points (of course the ultimate answer you can get from the author of the code `:)`).

So, Spring is a "dependency" injection framework (I emphasize a word "dependency" here). This means that Injection works great for dependencies (like controller that has an @Autowire-d Service).

Now DTOs are not dependencies. Dependency usually means some contract you want to use (by means of injecting something that obeys this contract, read an interface of dependent bean). DTO don't have a contract for functionality, they're more like objects that are constructed by service / passed to service to encapsulate the data. So I don't count those as dependencies and therefore they should not be injected.

In a broader sense, using spring doesn't mean "don't use a new keyword" - it just means - "don't use a new keyword for creating dependencies", at least from my standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

@Autowire is used to inject a bean.  A bean is typically a singleton (only one instance is created and shared among all beans it is injected into) and itself may have other beans autowired, such as configurations or database connections.  In order for all of this wiring to work Spring must be responsible for instantiating the bean.

If none of these features are required, and you simply need to create a new unique instance of a plain java object, then you just instantiate it via new().